# Find the matrix representation of $\psi\varphi^{-2}+2\varphi+I$

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be a linear transformation in vector space $V$, and given the inverse linear transformation of $\varphi$ exists, and the matrix representation of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ on the first basis of $V$ to be matrices $A$ and $B$, respectively, the transition matrix of $V$ from the first basis to second basis is $P$. Find the matrix representation $\psi\varphi^{-2}+2\varphi+I$ (where $I$ is the identity transformation on $V$) on the second basis of $V$.

I should find the matrix representation of $\psi\varphi^{-2}+2\varphi+I$ separately,  i.e. find the martix representation of $\psi\varphi^{-2}$, $2\varphi$ and $I$, respectively, by linearity property. What makes me feel difficulty is to find the matrix representation of $\psi\varphi^{-2}$, any idea to deal with it?

[Transition matrix in here refers to the matrix associated with a change of basis for a vector space.(Source: Wikipedia)]

The answer given for this question is $P^{-1}BA^{-2}P+2P^{-1}AP+I_{n}$.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that for any matrices $A$ and $B$ you have $(P^{-1} A P) (P^{-1} B P) = P^{-1} A (P P^{-1}) B P = P^{-1} (AB) P$; i.e., it doesn't matter if you change the basis of matrices before or after multiplying them. Does this help?

Comment: Nope, I am struggling in the inverse linear transformation of $\varphi$ and its matrix representation on second basis of $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

remember that, if the inverse exist,  $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$,

so also:

$(P^{-1}AP)^{-1}=P^{-1}A^{-1}P$

and note that:

$(P^{-1}MP)^{2}=(P^{-1}MP)(P^{-1}MP)=P^{-1}M^2P$

Comment: But $(P^{-1}BP)(P^{-1}AP)^{-2}=P^{-1}BP^{-1}A^{-2}P^{2}$.

Comment: No it doesn't. $(P^{-1}XP)^k=P^{-1}X^k P$.

Comment: Oops, I know what's my mistake here. $(P^{-1}AP)^{k}=(P^{-1}AP)(P^{-1}AP)\cdots(P^{-1}AP)=P^{-1}A^{k}P$ works here.

Comment: I added to my hint another hint....:)